# Contact Form via Controller in Umbraco 9

Tags: controller, smtp, contact-form, umbraco9

I'm trying to create a contact form via smtp in Umbraco 9 CMS. I tried several solutions, which all didn't work out. My last attempt was to make a view-file (Kontaktformular.cshtml), a controller (FormController.cs) and an integration in Startup.cs. When I send the form it says: Could not find a Surface controller route in the RouteTable for controller name FormController. Now am at the point, where I don't know, what else I should do, to make that form work. The namespace and the path of the controller is correct.

It would be great, if anybody could help me with that. You can see me code below.

Thank you!

Startup.cs:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Serilog;
using Serilog.Context;
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Umbraco.Cms.Core.DependencyInjection;
using Umbraco.Cms.Web.BackOffice.Controllers;
using Umbraco.Extensions;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Umbraco.Cms.Web;
using Umbraco.Cms.Web.Common.Controllers;


namespace Umbraco9.Web
{
    public class Startup
    {
        private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _env;
        private readonly IConfiguration _config;

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="Startup" /> class.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="webHostEnvironment">The web hosting environment.</param>
        /// <param name="config">The configuration.</param>
        /// <remarks>
        /// Only a few services are possible to be injected here https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/9337
        /// </remarks>
        public Startup(IWebHostEnvironment webHostEnvironment, IConfiguration config)
        {
            _env = webHostEnvironment ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(webHostEnvironment));
            _config = config ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(config));
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Configures the services.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="services">The services.</param>
        /// <remarks>
        /// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        /// For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
        /// </remarks>
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddUmbraco(_env, _config)
                .AddBackOffice()
                .AddWebsite()
                .AddComposers()
                .Build();

            services.AddRouting();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Configures the application.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="app">The application builder.</param>
        /// <param name="env">The web hosting environment.</param>
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {   
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseStatusCodePages();

            app.UseUmbraco()
                .WithMiddleware(u =>
                {
                    u.UseBackOffice();
                    u.UseWebsite();
                })
                .WithEndpoints(u =>
                {
                    u.UseInstallerEndpoints();
                    u.UseBackOfficeEndpoints();
                    u.UseWebsiteEndpoints();
                });

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "FormController",
                    pattern: "Form/{action}",
                    defaults: new { controller = "FormController", action = "Index" }
                );

                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });

        }
    }
}
```

Kontaktformular.cshtml:

```
@using Umbraco.Cms.Core.Models
@using Umbraco.Cms.Web.Common.PublishedModels;
@using ContentModels = Umbraco.Cms.Web.Common.PublishedModels;
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
@using Umbraco.Cms.Core.Models.PublishedContent;
@using Umbraco.Cms.Web.Common.Controllers;


@{
    Layout = "Master.cshtml";
}

<section class="formulate">
    <div class="container">
        @using (Html.BeginUmbracoForm("SubmitForm", "FormController", FormMethod.Post))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            <fieldset>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="firstName">Vorname</label>
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        name="firstName"
                        class="form-control"
                        placeholder="Vorname eingeben"
                        value=""
                        required 
                    />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="lastName">Nachname</label>
                    <input
                        type="text"
                       name="lastName"
                        class="form-control"
                        placeholder="Nachname eingeben"
                        value=""
                        required 
                    />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email">E-Mail</label>
                    <input
                        type="email"
                        name="email"
                        class="form-control"
                        placeholder="E-Mail eingeben"
                        value=""
                        required
                    />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="subject">Betreff</label>
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        name="subject"
                        class="form-control"
                        placeholder="Betreff eingeben"
                        value="" 
                    />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="message">Nachricht</label>
                    <textarea
                        type="textarea"
                        name="message"
                        class="form-control"
                        value="">
                    </textarea>
                </div>
                <button
                    type="submit"
                    name="Submit"
                    value="send"
                    class="btn btn-primary">
                    Senden
                </button>
            </fieldset>
        }
    </div> <!-- /.container -->
</section> <!-- /.formulate -->
```

FormController.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Umbraco.Cms.Core.Models.PublishedContent;
using Umbraco.Cms.Core.Routing;
using Umbraco.Cms.Core.Web;
using Umbraco.Extensions;

namespace Umbraco9.Web.Controllers
{
    public class FormController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IUmbracoContextAccessor _umbracoContextAccessor;
        private readonly IPublishedUrlProvider _publishedUrlProvider;

        public FormController(IUmbracoContextAccessor umbracoContextAccessor, IPublishedUrlProvider publishedUrlProvider)
        {
            _umbracoContextAccessor = umbracoContextAccessor ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(umbracoContextAccessor));
            _publishedUrlProvider = publishedUrlProvider ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(publishedUrlProvider));
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult RenderForm()
        {
            return PartialView("ContactForm");
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public IActionResult SubmitForm(IFormCollection form)
        {
            string firstName = form["firstName"];
            string lastName = form["lastName"];
            string email = form["email"];
            string subject = form["subject"];
            string message = form["message"];

            // E-Mail-Einstellungen
            string senderEmail = ""; // Absender-E-Mail-Adresse
            string receiverEmail = ""; // Empfänger-E-Mail-Adresse
            string password = ""; // E-Mail-Passwort
            string smtpHost = "send.smtp.com"; // SMTP-Host
            int smtpPort = 25; // SMTP-Port

            // E-Mail erstellen
            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
            mail.From = new MailAddress(senderEmail);
            mail.To.Add(receiverEmail);
            mail.Subject = subject;
            mail.Body = $"Name: {firstName} {lastName}\nEmail: {email}\n\n{message}";

            // SMTP-Client erstellen und E-Mail senden
            SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient(smtpHost, smtpPort);
            smtpClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(senderEmail, password);
            smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
            smtpClient.Send(mail);

            // Umleitung zur aktuellen Umbraco-Seite
            IPublishedContent currentPage = _umbracoContextAccessor.GetRequiredUmbracoContext().PublishedRequest.PublishedContent;
            string currentPageUrl = _publishedUrlProvider.GetUrl(currentPage, UrlMode.Absolute);
            return Redirect(currentPageUrl);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a SurfaceController, not a Controller. Take a look at the docs:
https://docs.umbraco.com/umbraco-cms/reference/routing/surface-controllers/